# How to set placeholder text in ASP.NET MVC TextBox

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, viewdata

I have a simple Newsletter signup form on my page with 2 textboxes (Name,Email) and a submit button.  Upon successful submission, I want to display a success statement using ViewData["Message"].  Prior to wrapping the form in an if statement I could use default text values and jQuery events on it, but after wrapping it doesn't work.  Here's the code;

```
@if (ViewData["Message"] != null)
{
    <span class="visitWriteup">Thank You for Signing Up for Our Newsletter!</span>
}
else
{

    using (Html.BeginForm("MailingList", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "MailingListForm" }))
    {
        <span class="visitWriteup">
            Sign Up for Our Newsletter:
        </span>
        <span class="SignUpText">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @Value = "Name:" })

        </span>
        <span class="SignUpText">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @Value = "E-Mail:" })

        </span>
        <span class="errorText">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)</span>
        <span class="errorText">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)</span>
        <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btnSubmit" value="Subscribe" />
    }
}
```

The form not displays without the "Name:" and "E-Mail:" Values in the textboxes and my jQuery functions aren't working correctly either.

```
$(function () {
   $('#Name').click(function () {
       if (this.value == 'Name:' || this.value == '') {
        $(this).val('');
       }
    });
   $('#Name').blur(function () {
       if (this.value == '') {
          $(this).val('Name:');
       }
    });
});
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could use a `placeholder="Name"` attribute on the textarea, and remove all this logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its seems you are setting `placeholder` text in the input fields in wrong way. Please do as follows:

```
<span class="SignUpText">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { placeholder="Name" })
</span>
<span class="SignUpText">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { placeholder="E-mail" })
</span>
```

Now you don't need to do anything with `jQuery`.